# why does c# have more books about LINQ than vb

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I'm starting a new project to handle info from some text files, a kind of sorting module so I'd like to give it a try using LINQ but looking for a book I realized that there are more c# books than vb, so I wonder if c# have better support or if it is more suitable than vb.

You think there is some advance on use c# or vb.

thanks.

Comment: Ummm, because more people use C# than VB.NET? Remember that books are (usually) written for people, not software (besides OCRs). You could easily ask "Why does C# have more questions on Stack Overflow than VB.NET?" and you'd get the same answer.

Comment: this was upvoted? seriously???

Comment: @CloseVoter#5: Please don't send this to programmers...

Comment: @Jeff Mercado - Closed :) Though I did answer!

Comment: If you are looking for a discussion of LINQ with VB, our LINQ in Action book does cover differences where they appear and we include all code samples in C# and VB. Also, Apress has a VB version of their LINQ book.

Answer (score 4):

Better question: Why are there more books for C# than VB.

More developers use it. Simple as that.

http://www.telerikwatch.com/2008/04/survey-says-c-more-popular-than-vb.html

Interesting links on Adoption of C# and VB: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Visual_Basic_.NET#Adoption_and_community_support

Most importantly for this question: `Stephen Wiley, marketing product manager at Apress has reported "C# titles outsell VB.NET title books handily, by somewhere between a 2–1 and 3–1 margin."`

So if you are looking for community support, I would say C# is the way to go, though MS does support both equally.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the languages are the same, but there is a big difference in the perception of the languages and the types of examples and books available.  In many cases you'll find more advanced examples in C# and advanced books in C# (not all, but many).  You'll also often see people refer to C# as a superior language, not for any real technical reason but really from a matter of perception.

In my personal experience, you'll also see a difference in pay scales for C# developers vs VB.NET developers.

If you're just starting out, then I would recommend C# and not VB.NET.  Again, not for any true technical difference, but because of the perception and available learning materials.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, its all syntax - especially in .net, because they compile down to be used by the same runtime engine. Perception is a big part, because c# looks more 'authentic', but its more based on perception. Also, c# syntax is very much like java, which is a language highly reverred amongst programmers. So, the natural progression says that more people will probably use c# than vb, and vb.net's grandfather (vb6) wasn't a good language...hence there are more resources for it..

Comment: -1 for C# looks more 'authentic', java is highly reverred, and VB6 wasn't a good language. We need references to back up these statements please!

Comment: @matt - talk to a few java programmers, and VB6 programmers - you will get all the 'backup' you need :)

Comment: I can see you're a vb6 programmer :) didn't mean to offend, but I don't really want to get into a discussion as to why vb6 isn't a good language. I don't really like java much either, but most programmers will definitely tell you they respect it. Can't say the same for vb6. Again, not the place for that discussion :)

Comment: No offence taken - my one and only point is that you need to back up your argument with some references rather than just saying 'all silverlight development is bad because a bloke I met yesterday said so' (for example) until you can do that then my -1 stands

Comment: @matt, like I said - I will wholeheartedly debate that with you, given that I was once a vb6 programmer myself, but not on the comments forum.